# How to flip bits without leading signs in PHP?

Tags: php, binary, integer

On flipping/inverting bits in PHP using the `~`-operator the output contains a lot of leading signs, which are obviously unnecessary, if you output the raw integer. On parsing the binary-value back to an integer, you will see that the values are not equal. See the example attached below.

```
$integer = 0b11110; // raw integer
echo "{$integer}: " . decbin($integer) . PHP_EOL; // print integer-value before flipping
$integer = ~$integer; // flipping/inverting the integer

$binary = decbin($integer);
echo "{$integer}: " . $binary . PHP_EOL; // print integer-value after flipping
echo bindec($binary) . PHP_EOL; // print parsed binary-value
```

[see result on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7G9rV)

Is it possible to remove the leading signs, so that the second usage of echo will output something like `100001` (or just `00001`, if you don't take the plus/minus sign into account), because `-31` is obviously not the same as `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001`.

Comment: You probably want an unsigned integer.

Comment: -31 is indeed the same as that bit sequence, in 64-bit two's complement.

Comment: There's only _one_ leading sign bit.   The other ones following that are significant.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth But binary is the same as two's complement. I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: what are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Look at the last result of the last example in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php#refsect1-function.bindec-examples